# QuickDialog Line of Code/Detect Value Change

Tags: objective-c, xcode, quickdialog

I am working with QuickDialog OpenSource and I am not sure how to detect when value has changed for each of the QElement cells like QPickerElement.

I looked into the examples and they had:

```
__weak QPickerElement *_sysPicker = self.systemPicker;

        _sysPicker.onValueChanged = ^(QRootElement *el){
            NSLog(@"Selected ASSAFindexes: %@", [_sysPicker.selectedIndexes componentsJoinedByString:@","]);
        };
```

Which I am not sure why it executes whenever sysPicker value changes. Where would I put this line of code? Is there other ways to detect change, this seems weird.

Thanks,
Alan